# Flutter on ios simulator crash with error after `Configuring the default Firebase app`

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I use codemagic to test my app on a simulator.

the app takes more than half an hour to build and when I try to do `flutter run` I get

```
Configuring the default Firebase app...
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9adcce __exceptionPreprocess + 350
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b8199b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9adb0c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
        3   Runner                              0x0000000101dac652 +[FIRApp configure] + 130
        4   Runner                              0x00000001023c64b9 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 217
        5   Runner                              0x00000001023c62c6 +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 262
        6   Runner                              0x0000000101d477ff +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 207
        7   Runner                        <…>
```

NOTE: I was following this tutorial https://blog.codemagic.io/remote-access-to-virtual-mac-build-machine/

Comment: Did you setup firebase in Xcode https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?

Comment: @Sami Haddad yes that was the problem - I needed to create an ios app in the Firestore console